# A table row was 2 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (1)

Tags: html, css

I want to validate my page but w3c keeps giving me this warning. I want to get rid of it but I can't seem to find the cause of it.

It gives me this error:

> A table row was 2 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (1).

Table and CSS code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Contact informatie</td>
    <tr>
    <td>Adres:</td>
    <td>Jan van der Heydenstraat 61</td>
    <tr>
<td>Postcode:</td>
<td>1223 BG</td>
<tr>
<td>Plaats:</td>
<td>Hilversum</td>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td>info@blabla.nl</td>
<tr>
<td>Telefoon:</td>
<td>06-31903706</td>
</tr>
</table>

table {
    border:none;
    padding-left:75px;}

td:first-child {
    width:135px;
    border:none;
    text-align:left;}

td+td {
    border:none;
    text-align: left;}
```

Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: see my anser which should work

Answer (score 6):

It means exactly what it says. One of the rows in your table has too many columns. Specifically, the first row has less columns that a subsequent row. But we can't do much unless you post some code.

**Edit**

The markup for the table is incorrect.

- You only have one cell in the first row (or do what PeeHaa suggested)
- You need to close off *each* row with `</tr>`

Comment: Yet another case of "RTFEC". I'll leave y'all to work out what that acronym is...

Comment: @SimpleCoder I've added a shameful `C`. Thanks for the the UD reference xD

Comment: Well the first problem I see is you are nesting a table row inside of a table row without closing the first row

Answer (score 5):

Just change this:

```
<tr>
<td>Contact informatie</td>
</tr>
```

To this:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Contact informatie</td>
</tr>
```

YOu should always close you tablerows (`tr`): `</tr>`.

Final version:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Contact informatie</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adres:</td>
    <td>Jan van der Heydenstraat 61</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Postcode:</td>
    <td>1223 BG</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Plaats:</td>
    <td>Hilversum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td>info@vazcreations.nl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Telefoon:</td>
    <td>06-31903706</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

In extension to what SimpleCoder said, if you have the first row of a table have only one column, then the futher ones can have no more then one column. If you want to get around this you need to put a table inside the cell i.e.

```
    <td>
       <table>
          <tr>
             <td><!-- Content here --></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
```

Comment: ` If you want to get around this you need to put a table inside the cell` Or use `colspan` which is what it is for.

Comment: Or drop using tables for layout and use css positioning on block elements

Comment: Where do you see that it is used for layouting?

Comment: The markup that was posted previously inside the comments ^^, but i didnt know about the `colspan`, wait but don't no browsers support it?